# What is operator overloading and is it different from Polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I program in Java and have been trying to understand exactly what operator overloading is. I'm still a bit puzzled.

An operator can take on different meanings depending on which class uses it? I've read that it is "Name Polymorphism".

Java apparently does not support it and there seems to be a lot of controversy around this. Should I worry about this?

As a last question, in an assignment the teacher has stated that the assignment uses operator overloading, he is a C++ programmer mainly but we are allowed to write the assignment in Java. since Java does not support overloading, is there something I should be wary of?

Comment: operator overloading cannot be done in Java; it is done in C++ (though other languages may support it as well). Basically you create your own operators and make them do whatever you want. You could redefine - to add 2 numbers instead of subtract them. You can define + for complex numbers, for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Operator overloading basically means to use the same operator for different data types. And get different but similar behaviour because of this.

Java indeed doesn't support this but any situation where something like this could be useful, you can easily work around it in Java.

The only overloaded operator in Java is the arithmetic `+` operator. When used with numbers (`int`, `long`, `double` etc.), it adds them, just as you would expect. When used with `String` objects, it concatenates them. For example:

```
String a = "This is ";
String b = " a String";
String c = a + b;
System.out.print (c);
```

This would print the following on the screen: `This is a String`.

This is the only situation in Java in which you can talk about operator overloading.

Regarding your assignment: if the requirement is to do something that involves operator overloading, you can't do this in Java. Ask your teacher exactly what language you are allowed to use for this particular assignment. You will most likely need to do it in C++.

PS: In case of `Integer`, `Long`, `Double` etc. objects, it would also work because of unboxing.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't allow overloading operators. It uses a very limited kind of operator overloading though, since `+` does addition or concatenation depending on the context.

If your assignment asks you to implement something by overloading operators, you won't be able to do it in Java. Maybe you should ask the teacher why he allows Java for such an assignment.

If your assignment only asks you to use an overloaded operator, then having your program use `+` for concatenation and addition would fit the bill. But I would ask the teacher, because I doubt that it's what he expects.

Answer (score 1):

> Java apparently does not support it and there seems to be a lot of
>   controversy around this.

There is *no* controversy about this.  Some people might disagree with the decision, but James Gosling and others decided from day one to leave operator overloading *by class developers* out of the language.  It's not likely to change.

As pointed out by others here, they reserved the right for the JVM to overload operators on a limited basis.  The point is that you can't do it when you're developing your own classes.

They did it because there were examples of C++ developers abusing the capability (e.g. overloading the dot operator.)

> Should I worry about this?

No.  Java won't explode.  You just won't be able to do it for your classes.  If you feel like you need to, you'll just have to write C++ or some other language.

Answer (score 0):

Can either use natural a != b (a is not equal to b) or a.Equals(b)

```
b.set(1, 0);
a = b; 
b.set(2, 0);
assert( !a.Equals(b) );
```

But java has a limited set of operator overloading than other languages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading

Answer (score 0):

As to your query about the difference between operator overloading and polymorphism. Polymorphism is a standard OOP concept where an instance of a class may exhibit different characteristics depending on the underlying type. For example in C++:

```
class Shape {
...
virtual void draw()=0;
}

class Circle :public Shape {
virtual void draw() {...draw a circle...}
}

class Square:public Shape {
virtual void draw() {...draw a square...}
}

..

Shape *s = new Circle();
s->draw(); // calls Circle::draw();
s=new Square(); // calls Square::draw();
```

Hence s is exhibiting polymorphism.

This is different from operator overloading but you already have been explained what that is in the other answers.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that operator overloading is a simpler form of polymorphism?

Comment: IMHO no as polymorphism means exhibiting many forms. Function overloading is closer to polymorphism I guess.